# “have/get your car checked” or inspected/serviced?

Tags: idioms, expressions, american-english, british-english, causatives

> Before a long distance journey it is wise to
>
> 1. have/get your car checked
> 2. to check the car
> 3. do an MOT (a Ministry of Transport test)
> 4. service the car
> 5. inspect the car
> 6. have/get your car inspected

I am specifically referring to inspecting the general wear and tear of a vehicle, not the yearly exam imposed by governments. So, I know that No 3. may be technically incorrect but would a British motorist say it because it's quicker to understand?

*Collins Dictionary* has an entry for [**service a car**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/service-a-car) but turns up empty-handed for "check a car" or "car checked". Similarly, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/check) does not have relevant examples for "check" in its UK dictionary whereas it does for [**service**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/service)

> **6.** A periodic routine inspection and maintenance of a vehicle or other machine.
>
> ‘*he took his car in for a service*’

In British or American English can I say the following, and will I be understood?

> - I always **get my car checked** before a long road trip.

The fact I did not find any reliable references makes me think that native speakers might find it odd or foreign to their ears. Is there a more common expression?

Comment: A British motorist will only say an 'MOT test' if that is **exactly** what they mean (the government-decreed safety test for cars over three years old).

Comment: The MOT test certificate only means your car was legal on the day it was tested. It does not necessarily mean that it is good for a long journey.

Comment: And _servicing_ is something that the car manufacturer recommends you to have done at stated intervals in the car's life. If it isn't due for a service, you would just have it _checked_.

Comment: It is possible for British drivers to get an MOT test done long before one is due, to find out if any faults need repairing. They would explicitly call it 'getting an MOT'. There is a danger though. If the car fails the test, that immediately invalidates the existing certificate, and makes it illegal to drive the car on public roads.  The failure will be recorded on the national database, potentially alerting the vehicle to the traffic police. In any case, an MOT says nothing about the reliability of the car.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am a car owner in Italy and as such I have never had it MOTed in the UK. In Italy the mechanic who does the "revisione" will tell you what parts need to be repaired or replaced,  the cost is extra. Once the test is completed and the necessary work done, your car is deemed safe to drive. Can a car pass the MOT in the UK  but still be unsafe/unreliable?

Comment: A car can pass the MOT but be not reliable for a long journey. The MOT tests some important items on a vehicle to check that they meet the legal standards. It isn’t the same as having your vehicle serviced and doesn’t check its general mechanical condition. The test doesn’t cover the condition of the: engine, clutch or gearbox. If any of these are worn, they could fail during a long journey, especially under the stress of high speed autoroute/freeway driving.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey OK, thanks for the clarification. From a British perspective, which is  more commonly heard: "Before every road trip he gets his car checked (or) serviced” ? A *posted* answer would be greatly appreciated.  :)) P.S Judging by the comments, it seems "get the car inspected" is unusual.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you only get your car _serviced_ when a service is due (it used to be every six months, but modern cars only need an annual service). There is an official list of things that should be checked on each occasion. A careful driver may get certain things checked in between times before a long journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are not all the same, at least in American English.

First, you have to consider whether you're checking the car yourself or you're having someone else do it. For example, if you **check the car**, it implies that you're doing it yourself. If you **get the car checked**, it implies that someone else is doing the checking. The same holds true for **inspect**. However, **service** is different. You would not typically say **service the car** (yourself), but you might say **get the car serviced**.

In terms of the words used, **inspect** would typically refer to a more formal event, such as a required annual inspection or having a mechanic inspect a car before you purchase it. You can use **inspect**, but it's less common.

**Check** and **service** refer to two different things because the task is a two-step process. First you **have the car checked** to identify anything that needs to be adjusted or fixed. Then you **have the car serviced** to perform the required maintenance. If you do it yourself, you would likely **check the car** and then **perform maintenance** or something more specific such as "top off the fluids" or "change the oil."

Answer (score 6):

In AmE, it sounds most idiomatic to my ears to simply say “get my car checked/serviced.” The other options don’t sound quite as natural or casual.

Answer (score 0):

In British English there is a term "**roadworthy**". See the Cambridge dictionary definition **[here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/roadworthy)**.

The UK government publishes "[**The Highway Code**](https://www.gov.uk/check-vehicle-safe)" which advises owners to check the roadworthiness of their vehicles before any long journey.

Your suggestion sounds perfectly natural:

> "I always get my car checked before a long road trip"

If you wanted to be a little more explicit you could also say:

> "I always ensure my car is roadworthy before a long road trip"

Comment: roadworth is very formal and regulatory.